# What happened to CreateMLUI? Has it been removed?

Tags: xcode, swift

In my Swift project in Xcode, `import CreateMLUI` says no such module.  Has this been replaced or just removed?

Comment: xcode is an IDE for several languages which one are you using? Where does CreateMLUI come from - ie where is its documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you have chosen to create a project for macOS when starting your Xcode project - as this module is only available for macOS. If you have chosen to start an iOS project, you will get the error message you're seeing.

Comment: No.  It seems to be gone in Monterey.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No it has been replaced
Solution ->

1. Xcode
2. Toolbar
3. Open Developer Tools
4. Create ML
5. Choose New Document
6. Choose an Image Classification
7. Give it the Training and Testing Data